# Spring Boot, testing controller with secret token, how to?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, mocking, microservices

In my microservice I have Spring boot controller which is receive also auth token from http request header and send it to another microservice for validation:

```java
@Autowired
private AuthService authService;

@GetMapping(path = "/find", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@Timed
@CrossOrigin
public ResponseEntity<?> find(
        @RequestParam(name = "contactId", required = true) final Long contactId,
        @RequestHeader(name = "secret-token", required = true) String token
) {

    boolean checkTokenValidationFromAuthServer = authService.checkTokenValidationFromAuthServer(token);

    if (!checkTokenValidationFromAuthServer) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("token is invalid");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Your contact here!");
}
```

Auth Service must be like this

```java
@Service
@Component
public class AuthService {

    public boolean checkTokenValidationFromAuthServer(String token){
        //make rest call to auth microservice
        //validate token, return false, or true

        return false;
    }
}
```

Basic test always will fail because I from test I do not know secret token, I want to mock or prevent controller from validation:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PoolApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private PoolController controller;

    @Test
    public void controllerInitializedCorrectly() {
        assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCall() {

        ResponseEntity<?> find = controller.find(1L, "token");

        assertThat(find.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
    }
}
```

I do not know what is the best strategy for this kind of cases.

Comment: First, you don't need to start the whole Spring context to run a unit test on a controller. All you need is to create an instance of the controller then call its method, and check it returns the correct value. Use Mockito, or the mockign framework you prefer, to mock its dependency (i.e. the service): make it return false and check if the controller bahaves correctly in that case. Make it return true, and check that the controller also behaves correctly in that case.

Comment: Side note: Annotating a service with `@Service` is sufficient to make is a Spring bean. the additional `@Component` annotation is redundant.